# Vuejs composition api with filepond Refreshes the page on successful upload

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, filepond

I am using the filepond to upload the images in vuejs, at backend I am using Laravel, the file gets uploaded successfully but it refreshes the whole page but sometime does not.
I have checked the other solution on stack as well but that did not help me out so I am putting it here .
Solutions tried but failed
-cache cleared
-browser cache cleared etc

Here is my code

```
<script setup>
import UserInvoiceTable from './UserInvoiceTable.vue'

// Import FilePond
import vueFilePond, { setOptions } from 'vue-filepond'

// Import plugins
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from 'filepond-plugin-image-preview'

import FilePondPluginFileValidateType from 'filepond-plugin-file-validate-type'

import FilePondPluginFileValidateSize from 'filepond-plugin-file-validate-size'


// Import styles
import 'filepond/dist/filepond.min.css'
import 'filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.css'

const emit = defineEmits([
  'roomImage',
])

// Create FilePond component
const FilePond = vueFilePond(FilePondPluginFileValidateType, FilePondPluginImagePreview,FilePondPluginFileValidateSize)

const isFormValid = ref(false)
const refForm = ref()
const csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
const myFiles = ref([])

const onSubmit = () => {
  refForm.value?.validate().then(({ valid }) => {
    if (valid) {
      alert('dfdfd')

      const selectedFiles = Array.from(myFiles)

      console.log(selectedFiles)

      const roomImage = {
        files: selectedFiles,
      }

   
      // Adding a new room
      emit('roomImage', roomImage)
      
      // emit('update:isDrawerOpen', false)
      nextTick(() => {
        refForm.value?.reset()
        refForm.value?.resetValidation()
      })
    }
  })
}


const handleFilePondInit = () => {
  
  console.log('FilePond has initialized')


  
  //const pond = this.$refs.pond.filepond

  //Add a hook to send the CSRF token with the request
  setOptions({
    server: {
      process: '/api/auth/filepond-upload',

      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken,

      },

    },

  })
}
</script>

<template>
  <FilePond
    ref="pond"
    name="test"
    class-name="my-pond"
    label-idle="Drop files here..."
    allow-multiple="true"
    accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
    :files="myFiles"
    @init="handleFilePondInit"
  />
</template>
```

Comment: Ahh I have resolved it ,if any body came across the same issue let me know I will share the answer